# Is Vogels a good choice for Amazon dynamoodb mapper with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, vogels

I see that no active development is going on from vogels page from a long time i.e, about 5 months https://github.com/ryanfitz/vogels

Are there any better options?

Has anyone faced issues with scalibility or I/O time with it?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using vogels on a project recently. While it seems like it isn't as well maintained as it used to be, it's still quite a nice API wrapper - certainly much nicer than using the SDK directly.

I haven't encountered any performance cost with it - it's really just assembling AWS SDK calls, and doesn't do anything too crazy. The code is simple enough that anything I was unsure about I can dive in and check it out, and the docs are pretty good.

However another option that I've found recently is this library, open sourced by Medium. It's promised based and looks well maintained:
https://github.com/Medium/dynamite

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Vogels for around 6 months now and it's done everything I've needed it to do. The raw dynamoDB api is too low level for what I need. I too noticed that the module wasn't being 'maintained' so I created a fork of the project and republished it to npm:

[npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynogels)

[github](https://github.com/clarkie/dynogels)

I'm actively working on it to bring it up to modern standards and looking for more contributors to help out.